# в vim не корректно работает langmap

Tags: vim

Почему в `vim`, при таком `langmap`, не работает `shift+h` на английском языке? С этим `langmap` работает только на русской раскладке, не пойму, в чём вообще может быть проблема, может мне кто-нибудь подсказать?

```
set langmap=!\\"№\\;%?ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕHГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ?;!@#$%&`qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl\\;'zxcvbnm\\,.~QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\\"ZXCVBNM<>?
```

Answer (score 2):

Маппим.

1. Пропишите в `.vimrc`

   ```
   set keymap=russian-jcukenwin
   set iminsert=0
   set imsearch=0
   highlight lCursor guifg=NONE guibg=Cyan
   ```

Словари для проверки орфографии

1. Создайте папку `mkdir -p ~/.vim/spell`
2. Выйдите и зайдите в vim
3. Пропишите команду `:setlocal spell spelllang=ru_yo,en_us`

   - Это даст возможность использовать словарь со словами через «ё»

Источники

- https://habrahabr.ru/post/98393/
- http://linsovet.org.ua/vim-force-ask-for-download-spellfiles

Comment: То о чём я спросил не работает по прежнему

Comment: Просто используйте предложенный мной способ и у вас все заработает

Comment: Использовал, не работает, да и зачем мне словари для проверки орфографии?

Comment: Покажите ваш конфигурационный файл

Comment: удалите из конфигурационного файла `set langmap=!\\"№\\;%?*ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕHГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТ‌​ЬБЮ?;!@#$%&*qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl\\;'zxcvbnm\\,.~QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\\"ZXCVBNM<>‌​? `

Comment: Тогда раскладка на русском языке вообще не работает.

Comment: Вы точно соблюдали инструкции?

Comment: Инуструкции из одного пункта? Пишу третий раз что да, точно использовал.

Comment: Тогда предпологаемый ответ кроется в установке плагина xkb-switch

http://lin-techdet.blogspot.ru/2012/12/vim-xkb-switch-libcall.html

Либо так https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vim#Vim_.D0.B8_.D1.80.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D1.8B

Comment: А можно всё-же посмотреть на вопрос и постараться ответить на него? Мне не нужны всякие-левые плагины где инструкций на английском языке страниц 20. И где насколько я понял всё равно не даётся то что мне нужно (что мне даёт лангмап). А если я не ошибаюсь даётся возможность вводить команды на русском языке в командном режиме. Я спросил про лангмап, и он меня устраивает на 100% кроме того что почему-то, по странным причинам не работает shift+h именно в английской раскладке, всё сделано правильно, всё остальное работает кроме этого, я и задал вопрос именно на этот счёт.

Comment: Хорошо. Напишите пожалуйста свою версию vim,  shift + h  у меня работает на обеих раскладках моя версия 7.4.2109 с настройками которыми писал выше

Comment: версия 7.4.2173